# How do I send data from an android wearable device to a phone in the form of a a simple text file containing data?

Tags: android, wear-os, data-transfer, wearables

I have a wearable app. The app after it finishes has data like time/date, UUID, Geo location, parameters selected displayed in front of me like a Data Report or Log in several TextViews underneath each other. Like a list. I want this data to be transferred from my wearable device to my android phone.

Now I have to ask does the WearOS app the pairs the phone with the watch enables such a thing? Like can the data be sent through it? OR what exactly can I do? I read about **Sync data items with the Data Layer API** in the documentation, but I'm not sure if the code snippets provided would help achieve what I want.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String COUNT_KEY = "com.example.key.count";
    private DataClient dataClient;
    private int count = 0;
    ...
    // Create a data map and put data in it
    private void increaseCounter() {
        PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create("/count");
        putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt(COUNT_KEY, count++);
        PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
        Task<DataItem> putDataTask = dataClient.putDataItem(putDataReq);
    }
  ...
}
```

The data I display in the textviews are called through methods that I call things like: getLocation, getUUID, getDateTime, getSelections, etc... when I click a button I call them in the setOnClickListener. I want this data in the TextViews to be placed in a file or something like that and send them over to the mobile phone from the watch when they're generated.

```
 private void getDateTime()
{
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat sdf_time = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss z");
    String currentDate= sdf_date.format(new Date());
    String currentTime= sdf_time.format(new Date());
    textView_date_time.setText("Date: "+currentDate+"\n"+"Time: "+currentTime);
}


 @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void getUUID()
{
// Retrieving the value using its keys the file name
// must be same in both saving and retrieving the data
        @SuppressLint("WrongConstant") SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("UUID_File", MODE_APPEND);
// The value will be default as empty string because for
// the very first time when the app is opened, there is nothing to show
        String theUUID = sh.getString(PREF_UNIQUE_ID, uniqueID);
// We can then use the data
        textView_UUID.setText("UUID: "+theUUID);
}
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
private void getSelections()
{
     textView_data_selected.setText("Tool No.: "+c.getToolNo()+
             "\nTool Size: " +c.getToolSizeStr()+
             "\nFrom Mode: " +c.getCurrentModeStr()+
             "\nGoto Mode: " +c.getModeStr()+
             "\nMethod: " +c.getMethodStr()+
             "\nBit Duration: " +c.getBitDuration()+
             "\nUpper bound" +c.getUpStageValue()+
             "\nLower bound: "+c.getDownStageValue());
    
}
```

The above are examples of the methods I use to get the data. then I call them here:

```
    gps_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
                    getLocation();
                    getDateTime();
                    getUUID();
                    getSelections();
                }
                else
                {
                    //ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(get_location.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
                    Toast.makeText(get_location.this,"Build SDK too low",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                }

            }
        });
```

Now how do I take all this and send it over from my device to the the phone?

**Note:** The data report I want to send as a file, I want it done subtly like something done in the background. I don't know what else to do or where to look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options if you want to use the Data Layer, one is to use the [MessageClient API](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/messages) to bundle your data up in a message and send it directly to the handheld. The easiest here would be to create an arbitrary `JSONObject` and serialize your data as a JSON string you can stuff into a message. For example:

```
try {
    final JSONObject object = new JSONObject();
    object.put("heart_rate", (int) event.values[0]);
    object.put("timestamp", Instant.now().toString());
    new MessageSender("/MessageChannel", object.toString(), getApplicationContext()).start();
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create JSON object");
}
```

In my case, I do this in my `onSensorChanged` implementation, but you can insert this wherever you are updating your text.

`MessageSender` is just a threaded wrapper around the MessageClient:

```
import java.util.List;

class MessageSender extends Thread {
    private static final String TAG = "MessageSender";

    String path;
    String message;
    Context context;

    MessageSender(String path, String message, Context context) {
        this.path = path;
        this.message = message;
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Task<List<Node>> nodeListTask = Wearable.getNodeClient(context.getApplicationContext()).getConnectedNodes();
            List<Node> nodes = Tasks.await(nodeListTask);
            byte[] payload = message.getBytes();

            for (Node node : nodes) {
                String nodeId = node.getId();
                Task<Integer> sendMessageTask = Wearable.getMessageClient(context).sendMessage(nodeId, this.path, payload);

                try {
                    Tasks.await(sendMessageTask);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    // TODO: Implement exception handling
                    Log.e(TAG, "Exception thrown");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception exception) {
            Log.e(TAG, exception.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The other option is to create a nested hierarchy of data items in the Data Layer and implement [DataClient.OnDataChangedListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/DataClient.OnDataChangedListener) on both sides, such that changes that are written in on one side are automatically synchronized with the other. You can find a good walkthrough on how to do that [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data/events).

For your specific case, just packing it in a JSON object would probably be the simplest. The writing out to your preferred file format you can then implement on the handheld side without needing to involve the wear side.